# Stick two divs in one major div

Tags: html, css-float

I know, that there is plenty of threads dealing with sticking two DIVs, but I can't get it work, maybe because Im having different composition of DIVs.

So, this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
</head>

<body>


<div id="up" style="display: inline-block; width:750px; height: 30px; border:1px solid black;">

<div id="titlebar" style="width: 400px; height: 100%; float: left; border: 1px solid red";>
</div>

<div id="swBtn" style="width: 50px; height: 100%;  float: right; border: 1px solid blue;">
</div>

<div id="meta" style="width: 200px; height: 100%; float:right; border: 1px solid red;">
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[picture](http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/1062/divse.png) will support your imagination.
(1.)) is the product of this code and second (2.)) is how I want it to work

so, you can see, that I want to stick blue square(swBtn div) to the LEFT side of the smaller red square (meta div), but it should be done in way, that it will stay sticked even if div with id=meta would change it's width.

Maybe it's trivial, but thanks for your answers!

Comment: use display:inline-block and for better performance don't use inline CSS

Comment: Im using display: inline-block in top div with id=up and it's not working nor it is when I assign it to any of other divs.. :(

Comment: use it last div as it has be to be inline with both div

Comment: really, it has no effect for me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/asPwL/1/ look this

Comment: look, please, to the picture that I have included within original post..
Your solution looks completely different like the one I want it to be.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/asPwL/2/ do this check out it almost similar to your pic

Comment: :) sorry but I have to do it exactly as I have shown to you.. I can't use your solution

Comment: means you want some space between red and blue?

Comment: yeah.. but the exact meaning is that I need to make <div id=meta/> kind of sticky to blue one <div id=swBtn/> no matter how long will <div id=meta/> be. But blue one <div id=meta/> should be NOT sticked to <div id=titlebar/>. Right side of the <div id=meta/> should be always sticked (float: right) to the enclosing <div id=up/>
just like picture is saying ;)
Thanks for trying!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/asPwL/3/ it is very similar to pic do some changes if you want in this

Comment: can't afford this..
just two things to solve: meta div sohuld be always sticked to right side of enclosing div with id="up" and swBtn div have to be sticked to meta div with its right side. meta and swBtn divs can't cross each other!

Comment: hey do u have idea of css use CSS tags do some changes in it play with CSS and you will learn...